# How do I use Ctrl-Shift keyboard shortcuts for Tmux, with Cygwin/Mintty?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, tmux, mintty

I want to use "1-step" keyboard shortcuts for Tmux, when used from Cygwin/Mintty. I can't get them to work, so for now I have to use the default "2-step" keyboard shortcuts for Tmux, which I don't like at all.

"1-step" shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

"2-step" ones:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>W</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>X</kbd>

My previous setup was Cygwin + [ConzoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console/), a Windows console with tabs and splits/panes. Unfortunately ConsoleZ still uses conhost.exe, the Windows console, with all its limitations. So I decided to use Mintty instead, which is a xterm-compatible console. However, Mintty doesn't have tabs or panes so I decided to use Tmux, since it can provide both.

However, due to console limitations, Tmux uses a command prefix which is the first "step" of any command. I've bound mine to Alt-a for convenience. So all the commands are Alt-a, let go of Alt-a, press something else. Not really ergonomic.

I've been checking the Mintty and Tmux documentation for anything that can help, but I'm probably still missing something.

So far I managed to bind [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate through tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533839/how-to-bind-ctrl-tab-and-ctrl-shift-tab-in-tmux-for-mintty). I've also found that [Mintty does emit some special escape sequences](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Keycodes#ctrl) for the shortcuts I want to use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><...></kbd>). However, I don't know how to bind those to the commands I want.

I also saw that Tmux can have keyboard shortcuts without prefix, by using:

```
bind-key -n <key> <command>
```

So in theory I'm really close.

The question is: how do I actually map the special escape sequences to commands? I think it should be doable using user-keys, just as in the example  for Ctrl-Tab, but how can I list or otherwise see the Tmux escape sequence generated by Mintty for the keyboard shortcuts I want?

The list would be: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→/↑/→/↓</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, maybe a few others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not using `TMux`, but I suspect you need to verify the Ctrl-Shift setting of `Mintty`

[image]

Comment: It was a mix of this setting and using a newer Tmux version. Cygwin comes with Tmux 2.5 and I had to compile and install Tmux 2.6 to have these shortcuts working.