# What are the .tmux.conf bindings for Ctrl-Shift keyboard shortcuts with Cygwin/Mintty?

Tags: tmux, mintty

My question is pretty much exactly as the post below, but the answers to the below post do not specify the lines added to .tmux.conf.  Specifically I would like to know how to bind ctrl-shift-A to "select-pane -L".  I am using tmux 2.6 with cygwin/mintty with the "Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts" option turned on.

[How do I use Ctrl-Shift keyboard shortcuts for Tmux, with Cygwin/Mintty?](https://superuser.com/questions/1253483/how-do-i-use-ctrl-shift-keyboard-shortcuts-for-tmux-with-cygwin-mintty)

I have not been able to get any of the following to work:

```
# try to specify ctrl-shift-A directly
bind-key -n C-S-A select-pane -L

# try to use mintty ctrl-shift-A character code for UTF-8
set -s user-keys[0] "\xC2\x81"
bind-key -n User0 select-pane -L

# try to use mintty ctrl-shift-A character code for ISO-8859
set -s user-keys[0] "\x81"
bind-key -n User0 select-pane -L
```

Some other useful links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533839/how-to-bind-ctrl-tab-and-ctrl-shift-tab-in-tmux-for-mintty

https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Keycodes#ctrl

Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks!

**Edit:**

after turning OFF "Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts" in mintty I was able to run the xxd command, hit [ctrl-shift-A], [enter] then [ctrl-d] and got the following output:

```
> xxd

00000000: c281 0a                                  ...
```

I believe this shows that ctrl-shift-A is now being registred as \xc2\x81 as the mintty Keycodes suggests.  However, I still can't get the tmux bindings to work after setting my .tmux.conf file to the following and sourcing the config:

```
bind-key -n \xc2\x81 select-pane -L
```

If I just type ctrl-shift-A inside of bash in mintty it gives the following: "bash: $'\302\201': command not found".  Not sure if that's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use octal syntax in combination with `user-keys` and "Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts" disabled:

```
set -s user-keys[0] "\302\201" # octal of ctrl+shift+a
bind-key -n User0 select-pane -L
```

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#PARSING_SYNTAX for more details. I believe you can also use the `\u` syntax.

You can get octal codes for keypresses by running `showkey -a` in WSLtty.

I could not find a way to keep both `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V` in `mintty` and `Ctrl+Shift+letter` bindings in `tmux`.